# GtkTreeView select row editing a column

Tags: gtk, gtktreeview

I'm working with c, glade and gtk2

One column is editable. Editing one value, scrolling to no visible row and select (clicking) on one of this rows, the cursor go to one third row. The row selected is near edited value on the same row displayed position that clicked.

I think the problem is when GtkTreeView receives focus (end edition) set the display on the first value and after this is selected the row.
Is possible to force the selected/focused row to be displayed on GtkTreeView focus-in signal.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the selection mode to GTK_SELECTION_BROWSE, then one row should always be selected

Comment: Nothing changes. Scrolling outside of the first visible rows, on the first mouse click, select and kept displayed the row, the second click starts editing the column but line disappears, the display moves to the first lines.